# Knives in Checked Luggage (USA to Venezuela)

Tags: usa, luggage, venezuela

If I planned to fly into either Valencia or Caracas, would a small knife or knives (3"-6" blade) cause concern to someone working in the (Venezuelan) airport, if it were in my checked luggage?

I've tried to read on local jurisdictions, but it seems there was a sweeping attempt to ban the sale and carry of all knives, along with guns and explosives, so I'm left wondering what is actually enforced at the airport.

I do not want to travel somewhere and cause a problem with the locals, or end up in a Venezuelan jail. The knives can be left at home (they are for outdoor/utility use), but I'd like to have them if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The USA border control [TSA](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items) website says it is fine. Looking at the [US State Travel Listing for Venezuela](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/venezuela.html) it doesn't mention restrictions on knives in hold luggage.

There is a discussion on this from 2011 at this forum: [Carrying knife into Venezuela?](http://www.bladeforums.com/forums/showthread.php/161218-Carrying-knife-into-Venezuela)

However, looking at how there is a high homicide count in Venezuela and [Air Canada suspending all flights](https://www.aircanada.com/en/news/trav_adv/140317.html) (announced March 19, 2014) you may have issues. The safest bet would be not to carry a knife in your hold luggage, but there doesn't seem to be an ban on you carrying it. Just doesn't seem like a wise choice.

Some airlines might have restrictions but I doubt it.

Comment: I may have answered my own question. Caribbean Airlines makes flights to Venezuela, and [specifically allows a dive knives in checked luggage](http://caribbean-airlines.com/index.php/plan-a-book/baggage-information), which is traditionally a large, fixed-blade knife. Combined with the forum post you provided, I think everything will be fine, save for a possible corrupt/belligerent airline official, solider, police officer, etc. Of course, I have yet to try it, so anyone researching using this question should take all this with a grain of salt.

Thank you!